# How can we check if an object has same values but different references in hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to have a HashMap that stores a fraction and the number of similar fractions.
Suppose I have two arrays as my input

```
int[] numerator = {1, 4, 1, 2};
int[] denominator = {2, 8, 3, 2};
```

I have a Fraction class that looks like

```
static class Fraction{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Fraction(int _x, int _y){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
};
```

And I create the fractions by looping through the given arrays (simplifying what has to be simplified) and adding the to the hashmap, as follows:

```
    int nSize = numerator.length;

    List<Fraction> fractions = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < nSize; i ++){
        int div = gcd(numerator[i], denominator[i]);

        numerator[i] = numerator[i] / div;
        denominator[i] = denominator[i] / div;

        Fraction currentFraction = new Fraction(numerator[i], denominator[i]);

        fractions.add(currentFraction);

        if( map.containsKey(currentFraction) )
            map.put(currentFraction, map.get(currentFraction) + 1 );
        else
            map.put(currentFraction, 1);
    }
```

However, instead of getting for example input:

```
Fraction: 1/2 has value:2
Fraction: 2/3 has value:1
Fraction: 3/1 has value:1
```

I get

```
Fraction: 1/2 has value:1
Fraction: 1/2 has value:1
Fraction: 2/3 has value:1
Fraction: 3/1 has value:1
```

I am aware that the hashmap saves the fractions as different objects because they have different reference (even though they have same numerator and denominator), but how can I achieve the result aforementioned?

Comment: Try overriding Fraction's equals and hashCode functions

Answer (score 1):

HashMap, as the name, will store the entity by using hash code. So make sure you are using simple and immutable value to play as the key.

In your case, I believe the key should be the `fraction` String like `1/2` etc.

Comment: That would be an option, but that is not going to work for different kind of objects is it? Like more complex ones. :)

Comment: You need to make sure the complex objects with the same hash code if you want to let them as key. So when you use them, override the hashcode method and equals method.